# How to split a Content Database within site

Tags: 2010, database

I have a very large content database & need to split it.
Is it possible to split a content database within a site collection? or I need to create a new site collection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible to have multiple content databases service a single site collection.  You would need to find a way to actually migrate the content from your one site collection to multiple site collections.

In situations where there is a single site collection that holds a bunch of sub-sites, such as in an Intranet scenario, I would look at moving the sub-site content to individual site collections for those departments.

In situations where you are doing large scale document management, I would look to use something like the Content Organizer to move the content to a series of back end site collections and content databases and then provide easy search and content roll up  features to make the experience as easy and transparent as possible.

To handle the content moves required for either scenario you could either:

- Move the content manually
- Write custom code or powershell scripts to move the content from source to destination
- Use a third party migration tool that can move the content from source to destination

Comment: Or look at using RBS to offload content to the filesystem and out of the content database.

Comment: Good call @PirateEric but RBS is not a perfect fix for all situations.  It doesn't always improve performance, and may add substantial complexity.

Comment: agreed, I assume this question is in response to his previous question about loading 100GB of pictures into a library.  RBS would be a worthwhile consideration in that regard.

Comment: @MikeOryszak One Word "WOW!".Thx

Comment: The 200 Gb limit still applies with RBS. RBS can be a good solution for cheaper storage, but don't count on it to make your collaboration content DBs any bigger.

Comment: @JorgeCarvalho there is no 200GB limit, though designing for best practices or scalability would likely lead to smaller content dbs.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx as you can see on this link, there IS a 200Gb support limit. Over 200Gb the hardware requirements to keep a supported Farm are much stricter. If you're happy running your farm in an unsupported state, then you're right, there's nothing stopping you from letting your DBs grow beyond that

Comment: @JorgeCarvalho It is a matter of interpretation.  As you can see, the row below it says that the limit is 4TB.  After 200GB need better SQL and hardware optimization.  Previously the guidance was much lower, but there was not actual technical change.  I advise customers to avoid going over 100GB as a "soft rule" to avoid the added complexity and headaches of having to perform the added optimization unless there is a seriously hard requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You could not split the site collection into multiple content databases.

You can only move your site collection to a new content DB, or export sub sites and make them a new site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825327(office.12).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825326(office.12).aspx